# Sonar-Maven-Plugin: The folder does not exist

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonar-maven-plugin

we're having trouble with building a project in Jenkins. First of all some details on what we're using:

- Jenkins 1.596.1
- SonarQube 4.4
- Java SE Development Kit, Update 92
- Maven 3.3.3
- sonar-maven-plugin 3.2

We're getting the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project : The folder 'path-to-project-workspace\-ear\pom.xml' does not exist for 'path:project-ear' (base directory = path-to-project-workspace\ [Help 1]

Technically this could obviously be a problem on developer side. But I've been checking everything and it looks like it should work.

Maybe someone here has encountered a similiar problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Does your project build on command line without any issue? Do you use any profiles to build your project?

Comment: The problem is fixed now, I updated the question accordingly. But thank you for your answer regardless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was indeed on developer side. It is working now.

Comment: It would be useful if you could share what was the problem.